# Is my dynamo a BLDC generator or PMSM generator?

Tags: generator, brushless-dc-motor

I want to ask you about a problem please.

I have bought an AC dynamo generator (the commercial name). First I don't know is it an AC synchronous generator or a BLDC generator. The dynamo has 12 poles and 9 coils.

I turn the dynamo by an AC drill and I have seen a back EMF not sinusoidal and not trapezoidal. It's between the two. (There's many harmonics.)

I took multiple samples of speed and voltage so I found

\$K_e = 0.004 V/RPM = 0.004 \cdot 60 \cdot 2 \cdot \pi = 1.5 V/rad/sec\$

and so \$K_t = K_e = 1.5\$;

Now I want to calculate what torque I should apply to take 0.5 A current .
The theoretical answer is

In PMSM \$T = 1.5 K_t \cdot i = 1.5 \cdot 1.5 \cdot 0.5 = 1.35 Nm;\$

In BLDC \$T = 2 K_t \cdot i = 2 \cdot 1.5 \cdot 0.5 = 1.5 Nm;\$

So what type of motor should it be?

And what current should I provide, \$I_{rms}\$ or \$I_{max}\$ or \$I_{phasetophase}\$?

Are my calculations right?

Comment: You said 9 coils. How many slots are there?

Comment: There are 9 slots

Comment: A 9 slot, 12 pole brushless motor will be a BLDC, not PMSM.

Comment: Aha very good 
but how did you know ?what is the rule to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all google the serial number. This may provide a link to the datasheet & this will inform yourself as to whether it is a BLAC or a BLDC machine.

From empirical measurement... It all depends on what you are exactly seeing. You have to remember that the waveform you are measuring is line-line and NOT phase voltage.

So is it a BLAC machine?  the Phase voltages would appear like:
[image]

And thus the line-line at the terminals would appear:

[image]

Thus a BLAC machine would be quite clear. NOTE. In theory the BackEMF is sinus, in practice & depending on build quality... it won't be

So is it a BLDC machine?  the Phase voltages would appear like:

[image]

And thus the line-line at the terminals would appear:

[image]

Comment: Hello JonRB,
The graph is like the last graph because I measured Line to line only so is it a bldc !?

Comment: I would say it is a very strong indication it is a BLDC. I only say "strong indication" because I have had some BLAC machines provide trap backEMF at low speed

Comment: okay Jon,
So I will use the rules on bldc, but is it true to calculate the torque by phase to phase or phase to center process ??
I think it's true, so ?

After that I will put  6 diodes and capacitor to convert the signal to dc and to have 600 mA on the leads of capacitor .
Can you continue with me ?

Comment: Hello 
No answer ?